# Задача в том, что нужно написать код, который будет делать обратный отсчет в консоли

Tags: javascript

Используйте Self Invoked Function для создания замыкания и setTimeout для задержки вывода.

```
(function () {
  let countdown = 5;

  for (; countdown > 0; countdown--) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(countdown), 1000);
  }
})();
```

Не понимаю логики... Почему вначале проходит циклом и только в конце выводится сразу пять 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173350/synchronous-and-asynchronous-loops-in-javascript

Comment: Асинхронное выполнение вызовет функцию в setTimeout только через секунду, но через эту секунду значение `countdown` будет уже `0` т.к. цикл завершится. В задаче уже описан вариант решения данной проблемы - создать замыкание, чтобы оставить только копию `countdown` на текущий момент, а не само значение. Смотрите дубликаты, там описаны все варианты решений.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
  let countdown = 5;
    
  function t(){
    console.log(countdown--);

    if(!countdown)
        clearInterval(timer);
  }

  let timer = setInterval(t, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: По условиям ТЗ надо использовать setTimeout)